# Adding an ad hoc lookup to Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I have a totally custom visualforce page, with a number of elements on it, backed by controller instance variables, and I'm using apex:inputField to successfully render them all perfectly.

I now wish to allow the user to "select" a contact, and then I have an Apex function to do some stuff to the chosen contact.

I have created a Contact instance variable (as per all the others) like so:

```
public Contact contactLookup { get; set; }
```

but then, on the VisualForce page, if I try to render the input via:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!contactLookup}" />
```

I get an error message:

```
    Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!contactLookup}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.
```

Which is fair enough "Contact" is not associated with an input type. So my question is, how do I get the good old "Look up" box to appear on the page?

As seen here, from another standard page, for Account:
[image: Account lookup]

I'm fully aware of how to do this when using a standard controller/custom field - but not when the lookup is merely backed by an instance variable like this?

Comment: Read this topic from Jeff Douglas: [Roll Your Own Salesforce “Lookup” Popup Window](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not reference a Sobject, reference its field instead. Correct way is:

```
public Account contactLookup { get; set; }

<apex:inputField value="{!contactLookup.contact}" />
```

`<apex:inputField>` binds with sObject's **field** not the whole sObject. If it is a lookup then it will have lookup style.

Comment: This is very interesting, and might lead to what I'm after, but the trouble is I'm purely after a Contact, not necessarily in the context of an Account or any parent object.

Comment: This done by self lookup on sObject. Contact don't have self lookup like Account. You have to create a self lookup on Contact to achieve this. @SimonLawrence

Comment: @responsive Contacts do have a self-lookup. What do you think `Contact.ReportsToId` is?

Comment: yes, apex:inputfield and standard field will work. <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.ReportsToId}"/>. That has been just slipped for memory... Api 2.5 i think. Thanks!

Comment: Using `Contact.ReportsToId` and then hooking into the selection for my own purposes works nicely (I hope) thank you guys.